How can I add forearms to an imported stl of these hands. I cant select the edges
Can anyone advise how I can add forearms to these imported stl hands?


You've already asked this question before and it was closed due to lack of details: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/327219/joining-an-imported-stl-to-a-model. At least add an image in Edit mode so that we can see the mesh and preferably share your Blend file too.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.
